# XSLT compare lists and output single node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to compare 2 lists and if there are 1 or more nodes that do not appear in the other list I want to output a single node in the resulting xml.

Example XML:

```
<Root>
  <Layers>
    <List1>
      <Name>test1</Name>
      <Name>test2</Name>
      <Name>test3</Name>
    </List1>
  </Layers>
  <MoreLayers>
    <List2>
      <Name>test1</Name>
      <Name>test4</Name>
      <Name>test5</Name>
    </List2>
  </MoreLayers>
</Root>
```

Which should see that test2 and test3 don't appear in List2 and give the following output:

```
<RootOut>
  <UniqueNames>Yes</UniqueNames>
</RootOut>
```

I've tried using a for-each loop on List1 and doing a key comparison with List2, but this ends up creating 1 node per unique name, so would output 2 `<UniqueNames>Yes</UniqueNames>` nodes in the output.  I'm sure there's something easy I'm missing, but I can't figure it out.

XSLT:

```
  <xsl:variable name="list1_names" select="/Root/Layers/List1/Name"/>

  <xsl:key name="list2_lookup" match="/Root/MoreLayers/List2" use="Name"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <RootOut>
      <xsl:call-template name="UniqueNames" />
    </policy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="UniqueNames">
        <xsl:for-each select="$list1_names">
          <xsl:if test="(not(key( 'list2_lookup', Name )))">
            <UniqueNames>Yes</UniqueNames>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="list2" match="List2/Name" use="." />

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <RootOut>
        <xsl:if test="Layers/List1/Name[not(key('list2', .))]">
            <UniqueNames>Yes</UniqueNames>
        </xsl:if>
    </RootOut>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this only tests if there are `Name`s in `List1` that do not appear in `List2`, not the other way round (your description is somewhat vague on this point).

---

Another option is to look at it from the opposite direction:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="list1" match="List1/Name" use="." />

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <RootOut>
        <xsl:if test="count(Layers/List1/Name) > count(key('list1', MoreLayers/List2/Name))">
            <UniqueNames>Yes</UniqueNames>
        </xsl:if>
    </RootOut>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.  I only care about whether something exists in List1 that does not exist in List2, not vice-versa.  I'll test this out and if it does what I want I'll go ahead and mark this the answer.